# Oracle: How to alias subquery and use it in WHERE with IN?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why is this not working?

```
WITH ids AS (SELECT unique id FROM table1 WHERE cd = :cd AND
                                                yr = :yr)
SELECT NVL(person_id, NULL) FROM table2 WHERE id IN ids
```

In my actual code, the statement ids is used twice. I made this post to find out how to alias subquery and then use it in WHERE along with IN, as seen above.

I get the error : `Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "IDS": invalid identifier`

Comment: NVL(person_id, NULL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cte is like a subquery, but it's not exactly the same, as your case illustrates. `IN` accepts a list of values or a subquery.

This should work fine:

```
SELECT NVL(person_id, NULL) 
FROM table2 
WHERE id IN (SELECT unique id 
             FROM table1 WHERE cd = :cd AND yr = :yr)
```

Update: You don't need to (can't) alias the subquery used with the `IN` operator, if you want to use the cte, you need a subquery that references it:

```
;WITH ids as (SELECT unique id 
              FROM table1 
              WHERE cd = :cd AND  yr = :yr)
SELECT NVL(person_id, NULL) 
FROM table2 WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM ids)
```

Comment: I had that originally, but I tried to alias the latter statement as in above. There is a reason I want to alias it, as that statement is twice in my code. I made this post to find out how to alias a subquery and then use that subquery in WHERE. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that such a feat is not possible. In accordance with Stackoverflow's Friendly Exchange policy, I will upvote your answer by 1 and accept your answer in t - 1 minutes. Thank you ever so much.